# Jruby Warble executable performance

Tags: glassfish, jruby, warbler

I am developing a JRuby on Rails app that needs to be deployed to clients servers. We want be able to compile the app so that the source can not be read and copied (easily). From what I've read Warbler seems to be the way to go.

My concern is the performance of the app in standalone mode. Meaning just runing as "java -jar MyApp.war" as opposed to using Glassfish..Tomcat..etc. The distributed app wont be high traffic, maybe 20-30 users max. If anything it'd be more heavy on the db side which is a separate issue.

So how does this type of scenario compare performance wise with running with an actual server?

Comment: The embedded Jetty is actually pretty speedy.

Answer (score 0):

Using Glassfish, Tomcat JBoss (or Torquebox) will perform just as good as long as the JVM has enough memory.

You will need to tweak loading\compiling the assets depending on the deployment server.

If it's supposed to be a web app then you will need the war\tomcat.  If it should be a desktop app then just use the jar version.